# Find which document is causing Mongo to hang

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

I have a map reduce job which always seems to hang on one document. I suspect that my map function is throwing it for an infinite loop somehow, but I can't figure out how. Is there any way to figure out which document is the one it's being hung up on? And ideally debug it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You may initialize a counter which is enough large in the map function. If looping reaches the counter then exit the loop and emit with special key (which won't be reduced is better) and the current document contents. You can find this document in the result collection with this(these) special key(s).

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there any way to figure out which document is the one it's being hung up on*

Make use of the `print()` function to print the `_id` of the document currently being processed, inside the `Map()` function **before** emitting:

```
var map = function() {
    print("Mapping "+this._id);
    emit(this._id, this.value);
};
```

> *And ideally debug it somehow*

The equivalent of java script's client side debugging statement, `console.log()`, in mongodb is the `print()` statement. It should be used for debugging purposes.

Refer: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/troubleshoot-map-function/

See Also: [mongodb: how to debug map/reduce on mongodb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527126/mongodb-how-to-debug-map-reduce-on-mongodb-shell)